# How to execute .sql file using another .sql file in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I try to start [cr_tb.sql](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/cr_tb.sql) file using another [start.sql](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/start.sql) file and get an error `unknown command beginning pid number...` The strange thing is that when I simply copy paste the [cr_tb.sql](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/cr_tb.sql) content into the SQL*Plus, it executes perfectly.

What am I doing wrong? (I have posted the dropbox links)

Comment: Seems like you have posted the same link for both files mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem lays in the `create table frclubs` statement. There are blank lines in

the table definition:

```
create table frclubs
(
    -- here they are

pid number(2) not null,
clubid number(2) not null,
constraint cPIDCLUBIDPK primary key(pid,clubid),
constraint fPIDFK foreign key(pid) references friends(pid),
constraint fCLUBIDFK foreign key(clubid) references clubs(clubid)
);
```

You have two choices:

1. Remove blank lines in the `create table frclubs` DDL statement;
2. Allow SQL*PLUS ignore blank lines in the script issuing `SET SQLBLANKLINES ON` command.

Comment: Can we conditionally execute statement? Like -

DECLARE
  counter int;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = UPPER('OOLD_SFWID_CHG_LOG_TAB_DESC');
  IF counter = 1 THEN  
     @C:\Users\umishra\Desktop\GE-5560\secondfile;
  END IF;
END;
/

But it does not work